# Delphi REST LifeCycle

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe2, datasnap

Why REST client connection, if Session LifeCycle is used on the server class, it behaves like Invocation LifeCycle?

Comment: see documentation: [Server Class LifeCycle](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Server_Class_LifeCycle)

Comment: I'm not sure the documentation is 100% accurate.  I created a REST web service using DataSnap.  It used a *Session* `LifeCycle` and I was able to maintain session variables for each client connection -- so long as they didn't disconnect (e.g., after each request).

Comment: The session vars works fine... but the objects created descendant of TDSServerModule (or TPersistent, or TComponent) and "published" by TDSServerClass not!

Comment: I've never had a problem with it.  If you provide a code sample of what you've tried, it would illustrate the issue...